# How to store and show sequential data changed in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The following code is a simpler version of my original problem. The code should do the following steps sequentially:

> 1. The table will show entire 'mtcars'
> 2. On each click on Half button, it should show half of the previous data
> 3. On each click on Double button, it should show Double of the previous data

Here the 'Half' button is working but double is working for first time only. 
Please help.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Table",
           actionButton("Half","Click for Half"),
           actionButton("Double","Click for Double"),
           DTOutput("tbl")
  )
))

server = function(input, output, session){
  mt_lst <- list(mtcars)


  data <- reactiveValues(
    tbl = mt_lst[[1]]
  )

  tbl <- eventReactive(T,data$tbl)

  observeEvent(input$Half,{

    mt_lst[[length(mt_lst) + 1]] <<- data$tbl[1:(round(nrow(data$tbl)/2)),]
    data$tbl <- mt_lst[[length(mt_lst)]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$Double,{
    data$tbl <-  mt_lst[[length(mt_lst) - 1]]
  })


  output$tbl <- renderDT(data$tbl)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Got it.. have to add mt_lst[[length(mt_lst)]] <<- NULL  in observeEvent(input$Double,{...

Comment: Be careful with `<<-` operator in shiny